# Trailing newlines get truncated from bash subshell

Tags: bash

Bash seems to remove trailing newlines from the output of subshells. For instance:

```
$ echo "Newline: '$(echo $'\n')'"
```

will produce the output

```
Newline: ''
```

Does anyone know a workaround or a way to prevent this truncation from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is just a newline in a variable:

```
nl=$'\n'
```

If you need to retain the newline, you can do this (which you show in your own answer):

```
f () { echo "hello"; }
output=$(f; echo "x")
output=${output%x}
echo "'$output'"
```

Resulting in:

```
'hello
'
```

Answer (score 1):

After some more experimentation I found a workaround using shell variables. Basically, I make sure that the output *does not* end in a newline, then I strip off the added text later

```
output="$(echo $'\n'x )"
output="${output%x}"
echo "Newline: '$output'"
```

This gives the proper output

```
Newline: '
'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `-e` option to enable interpretation of backslash escapes and do it all with one `echo`.

```
$ echo -e "Newline: '\n'"
```

will produce the output

```
Newline: '
'
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but I was just using the inner `echo $'\n'` as an example. My actual subshell was significantly more complicated.